# Motion Editor not working in Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I downloaded Android Studio 4.0 (canary channel) and I'm trying to create a motion layout but the editor is greyed out, an error that usually means there's something wrong with the dependencies. I have updated all the relevant ones I could think of (as seen below), and I've rebuilt the project (also done invalidating caches and restart), but the problem persists. What am I missing?

build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.aboutme"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.60-eap-25"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.60-eap-25"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- activity_main.xml -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motionLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/so_scene"
    tools:showPaths="true">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete `app/build/` directory and rebuild project then.

I had a problem like you describe though the issue was not with dependencies, but with `MotionLayout` class initialization in Motion Editor. You may check messages by clicking icon at the top right of Motion Editor (icon might be "info" or "warning"), like here:

[image: Warnings button in UI Editor]

I can't reproduce the error I had, but it was about missing attribute `motion_base` in `MotionScene` initialization. Removing the `app/build/` dir and getting it regenerated solved the issue.

Comment: I'd created a new project and it was working fine so after deleting all the generated files for the problematic project and removing the shortcuts from the quick menu, I was able to run it without any problems. I was aware of that warning icon, but with this particular problem, I don't remember seeing that. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: Tried all this but still stuck